# Understanding Layouts dimensioning

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm coming back to android after a lonnng break and I feel I've lost my modjo with it.

I'm trying to build a day-planning with a relative layout that I will populate with events later.

Here is the content view of my activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/day_main_relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/day_title_relative"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@color/blue" >

                <View //SEPARATOR
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@color/black" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/day_content_relative"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:background="@color/light_orange" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

the Planning is inside the ScrollView. The idea is that I fill ''day_main_relative'' with lines that I want to define the height of my relative layout. I've got to keep that dynamique, so I've done something like that :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Constants.HOUR_RANGE; i++) {

        // Cadrillage
        ViewGroup separator = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.week_separator_layout, planningMainLayout, false);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams separatorParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) separator
                .getLayoutParams();
        separatorParams.setMargins(0,
                DpHourLabel.convertValueToDpDay(i * 60), 0, 0);
        separator.setLayoutParams(separatorParams);
        planningMainLayout.addView(separator);
```

And then I'd like my Linearlayout inside of it to extend at maximum.

To make short I'd like something like that (with a black line from the SEPARATOR "View" element of my contentView):

[image]

but I obtain this:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a `listView`?

Comment: mostly because I can have like one event from 3h27 too 3h47 and one other 3H30 to 7H18 the events have to display well. anyway my question is mostly to undersand how layouts are built